# Why the component automatically was removed on collision event of the Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection

My English skill is poor I'm not a native English speaker.
Please understand.

I want to make the logic that detecting collision

For that, I make a character class. The Character class inherits the MonoBehaviour of the Unity system and has a feature as below.

1. The class has the container to put the skill was collided with own.
2. The class has the coroutine to show the status of the container. This coroutine starts when the Character class starts.
3. The class overrides OnTriggerEnter2D function of the Unity system. In this function, the skill that collides with own is added to the container.

I made the above feature as below code.

```
public class Character : MonoBehaviour
{
    private ConcurrentDictionary<Skill, float> _skills = new ConcurrentDictionary<Skill, float>();


    protected virtual void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(Check());
    }

    private IEnumerator Check()
    {
        float delayTime = 0.1f;

    First:
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(delayTime);

        foreach (var skill in _skills.Keys.ToList())
        {
            Debug.Log($"_skills: {skill}");
        }

        goto First;
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if(collision.gameObject.tag != "cold_wind") return;

        var skill = collision.GetComponent<Skill>();
        _skills.TryAdd(skill, 100);
    }
}
```

And I added BoxCollider2D component to the prefab that to add the above Character class.

After then I made the Skill class. I omit the Skill class because the Skill class doesn't have a feature yet. I added BoxCollider2D and RigidBody2D components to the prefab that to add the Skill class.

Finally I checked the Simulated function of the RigidBody2D to receive a collision event.

[image]

The program executes as the below sequence.

1. The skill is generated for 3 seconds and it collides with the character.
2. OnTriggerEnter2D function of the Character was called and skill that collided was added to the container. (Concurrent<Skill, float>)
3. The Check coroutine shows the skill be included in the container.

Here, I have the problem. Logically I think the Skill class included in the container must not be removed automatically.

But after 3 seconds (the skill effect appears for 3 seconds) if the skill effect disappears then the Skill class included in the container was removed. At the result Check coroutine shows null as below.

[image]

Could someone tell me what I did wrong?

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely everything you are doing is working as intended. The one mistake would be unexpected behavior with [`TryAdd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.tryadd?view=net-5.0), where the value added can be `null`.

Inside of your `OnTriggerEnter2D` function, add a check to determine what you collided with to only check for spells. The easiest way to do this is check the [`tag`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Tags.html) of the object. For all of your spells, add a tag that you can check against, then change your collision code to look something like

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if(collision.gameObject.tag == "SpellTagHere")
    {
        // the issue is this line can result in NULL if another object collides with your player
        var skill = collision.GetComponent<Skill>();
        
        // meaning a null is added here
        _skills.TryAdd(skill, 100);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I applied your advice to my code and update the article. but the problem doesn't disappear yet I created only one skill and make collide with the character. I checked that the skill is collided be added to the container. but after 3 seconds when the skill effect is disappeared the skill in the container also is removed.

Comment: @jjw Yes, that would be because you are not updating your list after it is deleted.  You would need to remove the spell from your data structure before it is deleted as a deleted object is still an object, but assign to `null`.

Comment: The Skill script file was added in the prefab named "cold_wind". If the skill effect created and collide with the character then the Skill script is added to the container. To here there is no problem but here I wonder <Is it normal when skill effect end the Skill script in the container also changed to null automatically?>

Comment: @jjw You are just storing references to objects that have a script on them. When the object is deleted, this reference is set to null as it no longer exists. If you are ever deleting the object or the script of the object, the reference in your data structure will go to null automatically, yes. You need to either remove it beforehand, or you can iterate over the list and remove nulls.

Comment: Oh... Thanks. I had thought wrong. If so could tell me how to do If want that remain Skill script in the container?

Comment: @jjw So you want to destroy the object but keep a reference to the skill when the object is destroyed? If that's the case, I would not keep the skill on the object as it would lose the reference. Possibly make a skill manager, then instead of storing a skill, store a reference to which skill is used in the manager. That way, the object can be destroyed but the reference will not as the skill reference is in a manager that is never destroyed.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I will make a skill manager and when the collision fired I will use the Skill script of the skill manager after compare if there is the skill that collided in the skill manager.

Comment: @jjw Another way is to just have a list of the skills and create an enum. Store the enum in the collision script, then grab the index by using the enum as an int. You'd have some sort of List<YourSkillScript> skillList and an enum called Skills skill, then access a skill by using skillList[(int)skill]. Do whatever makes sense to you tho as it will be easier to maintain.